# Attempted import error: 'withTranslation' is not exported from 'react-i18next'

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React nad I want to export a component but I get a error with 'withTranslation'

a summary of my code (version:"i18next": "^17.0.6","react-i18next": "^9.0.10",):

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
//version: "i18next": "^17.0.6","react-i18next": "^9.0.10",

//..........
//.............
class FromAlumno extends Component {
//................
//.....................
}

export default withTranslation("translation")(FromAlumno);
```

Comment: Are you importing it like - import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the exporting in your component, the problem is that you haven't imported withTranslation from react-i18next. Just switch your import to this:

```
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
```

I would recommend reading the documentation for react-i18next before posting here too.

https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc